# What is the preferred way to declare thread in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

We can declare thread in class using two ways

1. `extends Thread` class
2. `implements Runnable` interface

so which scenario is the best way?

Comment: Do you mean 'preferred' way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement Runnable, since you can extend only one class, and you might want to use it to extend something that cannot be implemented.

Comment: yes but we can extends Thread class in super class. am i right?

Comment: You can, there is nothing wrong with it, but it's just better to implement Runnable, in-case you might want to extend something now or later.
It's just about following a practice.

Comment: Sasikumar: Thread IS that superclass.

Comment: There's a better way to say that.  The `r` in `new Thread(r)` becomes the thread's _delegate_.  Using _delegation_ generally is a more powerful, more flexible way to structure a program than using inheritance.  It often makes code easier to test, and easier to modify.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "best", they're both good. There is most appropriate, though.

For over 90% of the cases, implementing Runnable is the way to go.
You should never extend Thread, unless you need to change the functionality provided by the Thread class.